# pynput: getting different outputs with pynput.keyboard.Listener.running (in "non-blocking fashion")

Tags: python, debugging, listener, pynput

In the "non-blocking fashion" of starting a `pynput` `Listener`, I'm getting different behaviors with the code below:

```
from time import sleep
import pynput

def stop(k):
    if k: 
        print("end")
        l.stop()

l = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=stop)

l.start()

print(l.running)

while True:
    if l.running: 
        print("running\n")
        sleep(1)
    else: break
```

Sometimes I get `False` and program ends. Other times, `False` then loop runs.
If I duplicate `print(l.running)`, I might event get `True`, for both statements.
Adding code after `l.start()` (e.g. duplicating `print(l.running)`) seems to increase the odds of getting `True` from `l.running`.
Finally, debugging instead of just running guarantees getting `True`.
It feels almost as if I need to provide enough time to the interpreter in order to `running` to be able to "catch" the listener working.

I've seen some posts on getting different outputs when running vs debugging, but they involved generating random values, usually in C++, or even misuse of variable scope.
They didn't seem very useful, at least to my poor knowledge.

Question is as straightforward as it gets: what is happening here?

I'm using VSCode on Windows11.

Comment: You should call `l.wait()` after creating the Listener - "Waits for this listener to become ready".

Answer (score 1):

A `pynput` listener runs on a separate thread to get keyboard input while your main program continues to execute. There could be a timing issue where the listener might not yet have registered as running when you check its status right away. The more time you provide by adding extra statements, the more likely you are to have the listener running when you check on it.

Also you're kinda creating a race condition: both the main program and the listener thread are accessing `l.running`. Depending on how the operating system schedules threads and when the listener thread updates `l.running`, the behaviour can be different.